# Tcl script does nothing when loading from file

Tags: linux, ssh, tcl, expect

I'm on Linux and trying to transfer some Tcl code that I had working over to this OS. I'm having problems though. Whenever I do:

```
./tclsh8.6 test.tcl
```

it gives me the output:

```
spawn ssh root@192.168.100.1
```

and then terminates. However, if I input the commands manually, it works fine. This is the output it gives me if I do it manually by doing:

```
./tclsh8.6
```

and then:

```
% #!/bin/sh
# \ exec tclsh "$0" ${1+"$@"}
package require Expect
spawn ssh root@192.168.100.1
% % 5.45.3
% spawn ssh root@192.168.100.1
14369
% send "admin\r"
% send "reset\r"
```

The command goes to my router and resets it. These are the contents of my test.tcl file:

```
#!/bin/sh
# \ exec tclsh "$0" ${1+"$@"}
package require Expect
spawn ssh root@192.168.100.1
send "admin\r"
send "reset\r"
after 3000
exit
```

Why doesn't it work when I run the script file? On Windows, all I have to do is double click on the .tcl file and it works. Why can't I get it to work on Linux?

Comment: Shouldn't there be some calls to `expect` in there too?

Comment: I'm not sure. The code works fine on Windows. I looked at what it's opening it with when I double click the file and it says it's using wish. I went back to Linux and tried wish, but I get an error that says the parameters for the send command are invalid.

Comment: I think the issue is in the script header. This command it's used to launch tcl interpeter on unix systems. When you execute the script step by step it ignore the instruction of second line. This is a line that tcl does not intepret as it is a comment and *\* at the end of the first line extend the comment to the second too. If you execute the script as an executable, it launch a sh and then exec the tclsh and then the script. Try to remove the first 2 lines.